# Parse JsonArray response data

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, nsarray

I have an json array respone like this;

```
[
    {
        "id": 62,
        "type_id": 1,
        "coordinate": {
            "x": 2273.73828125,
            "y": 1568.015625000001
        },
        "name": "x"
    },
    {
        "id": 57,
        "type_id": 1,
        "coordinate": {
            "x": 1405,
            "y": 343.99999999999704
        },
        "name": "y"
    }
]
```

I use alomifere 5.2 to get response. How can I parse this data to get all values?

Comment: Your outer object is an array, so you get an array of dictionaries. You can't cast an array to a dictionary.  You should use [`Codable`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6587213-alamofire-5-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

Comment: I edited my questions. Pls Check again. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Removing code from your question isn't really helpful or improving it. Did you read the tutorial I linked to?  Use Codable with AlamoFire to parse your response into an array of structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Alamofire.request("YOUR_URL", method:.post, parameters:params, encoding:URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
    switch(response.result)
    {
    case .success(_):
        if response.result.value != nil
        {
            let arr :[[String:Any]] = response.result.value! as! [[String:Any]]
            print(arr)
        }
        break

    case .failure(_):
        print(response.result.error)
        break
    }
}
```

Change successResponse as! [[string:Any]] (array of dictionary)

Comment: I edited my questions. Pls check again. Thanks

Comment: I recommended to use Codable. but here is my updated answer you can try this